# Обработка исключения для всех методов класса

Tags: c#

Есть класс со множеством методов но при выпадении определенного исключения (в любом из методов) например `IndexOutOfRangeException` должен стработать определенный обработчик, всегда одинаковый для любого метода. Есть ли способ и если есть то как этого можно добится кроме прописывания `try {} catch(){} finaly {}` в каждый метод отдельно ?

UPD:
Я пытался в конструктор класса добавить событие `UnhandledException`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
{
    //...обрабатываем исключение 
};
```

Далее в случайный метод добавил код, который приведет к исключению :

```
private void Somemethod()
{
    Convert.ToInt32("2.3");
     ....
```

Исключение выпало но не обработалось, в чем ошибка ?

Comment: *Исключение выпало но не обработалось, в чем ошибка ?* - вы в Debug-режиме?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да верно

Comment: Ну тогда надо нажать пуск еще раз и пойдет обработка `UnhandledException`, либо запускайте в Release

Comment: @АндрейNOP к сожалению это не решает проблемы. Может дело в том что я работаю не с .exe приложением а с unit Tests ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP тестовое консольное приложение нормально идет. а с тестами нужно как то иначе.

Comment: В юнит-тестах нужно явно указывать ожидание исключения в тестируемом методе, если исключение должно было произойти в данном тесте.

Comment: @rdorn т.е. без обертывания в try catch не обойтись ?

Comment: нет, просто это надо правильно оформить, тут есть примеры как http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/01/asserting-exceptions-in-mstest-with.html

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать AOP-инструменты, например PostSharp.

http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling

Минусы: лезет в скомпилированный код, требует установки у всех, кто будет работать над проектом.

Пример:

```
[PSerializable]
public class DisplayErrorAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{
    Type type;

    public DisplayErrorAttribute(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public override Type GetExceptionType(MethodBase method)
    {
        return this.type;
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.Message);
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
        args.ReturnValue = -1;
    }
}

[DisplayError(typeof(IndexOutOfRangeException))]
public class Test
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        var array = new int[] { 0 };
        Console.WriteLine(array[1]);
    }
    public void Bar()
    {
        var array = new int[] { 0 };
        Console.WriteLine(array[1]);
    }
    public void Baz()
    {
        var array = new int[] { 0 };
        Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.Foo();
        test.Bar();
        test.Baz();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Ошибка в методе Foo: Индекс находился вне границ массива. 
Ошибка в методе Bar: Индекс находился вне границ массива. 
0
```

Comment: т.е. каждому методу добавить `[PrintException]` а нельзя `OnException` вызвать при событии ?

Comment: @Сергей не знаю, если ничего не изменилось, атрибут можно подвесить на класс - и он будет работать для всех методов этого класса. Я такое использовал для логирования вызовов, работало.

Comment: Я имел в виду описать в классе некоторое событие которое отвечает за исключения и когда в любом участке кода сработает исключение то быдет вызываться определенный метод. Просто что бы меньше кода писать - все положить в одно событие. Если я правильно понимаю парадигму событийного программирования.

Comment: @Сергей при возникновении ошибки будет вызываться метод `OnException`. Накидал код с обработкой `OutOfRange` для любого метода класса, обновил ответ.